# Image is not respecting the size of the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div where there is an image inside that div. However I have a problem, that it is not respecting the size of the div, and it is overlapping it.

```css
.bs-col-md-6 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-flex-positive: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  0;
  */ -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.bsp-login-banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bsp-xs-hidden bsp-sm-hidden bs-col-md-6">
  <img class="bsp-login-banner" src="assets/img/Login.jpg" alt="the image is here" />
</div>
```

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Add overflow: hidden to the parent (.bs-col-md-6)

Comment: hi Pauline, not working overflow: hidden to bs-col-md-6

Comment: Probably because of position: fixed. Maybe put in a image-container with the correct size in there and have it fixed and overflow:hidden, and the image in there

Comment: Since your image has position fixed and its parent doesn't have position "relative", it is taking relative size to width of whole screen. Try setting **.bs-col-md-6**  's position to **position:'relative';** and that will make image take 50% of the parent's width

Comment: add image to post to result remove position:fixed and add overflow: hidden. Apparently it worked, but it got squeezed.

Comment: currently the image's width is set to 50% , do you want it to take 50% of the container?

Comment: position: 'relative'; it worked too. You didn't need overflow: hidden. However, the width of the image was squeezed.

Comment: if you want image to take whole of the container's width , then change **.bsp-login-banner** 's width to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `position: fixed` - this will completely take that element out of the context of all other elements (except the window/viewport).

It's not completely clear what you want, but you can use `position:absolute` instead and apply `position: relative`to its parent to make that the reference element for its position (and to some extent for its size, if defined).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the div some respectful size to handle this according to the image.

The concern with fixed positioning is that it can cause situations where the fixed element overlaps content such that it is inaccessible. The trick is having enough space to avoid that or using relative or absolute positioning instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bs-col-md-6 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-flex-positive: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  
  .bsp-login-banner {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    object-position: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bsp-xs-hidden bsp-sm-hidden bs-col-md-6">
      <img class="bsp-login-banner" src="assets/img/Login.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```